# How to get the X & Y on pinchopen and pinclose events in jgesture jquery library?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, mobile-safari, gesture

I'm using jGesture jquery library for gesture events. As per the documentation, delta and direction are not available for gesture events. 
http://jgestures.codeplex.com/documentation

```
$('body').bind('pinchopen pinchclose', function(el, ev) {
   if (ev.description === 'pinch:+1:open') {
      alert('pinchopen');
   } else if (ev.description === 'pinch:-1:close') {
      alert('pinchclose');
   }
});
```

I tried to use touchstart event to track the pageX and pageY once the figure is touched and use those coordinates in pinchopen/close events but these events does not invoke at the same time sometimes. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the workaround on this problem by storing the X & Y coordinates in TouchStart event in a global variable and used it in pinchopen/close events.

```
window.PageX = 0;
window.PageY = 0;

$('#mainContainer').bind('swipemove', function(event){ event.preventDefault();});
$('#mainContainer').bind('pinchopen pinchclose', function(el, ev) {
    if (ev.description === 'pinch:+1:open') {
       alert('pinchopen' + window.PageX);
    } else if (ev.description === 'pinch:-1:close') {
       alert('pinchclose' + window.PageY);
    }
});

document.getElementById('mainContainer').addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    window.PageX = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
    window.PageY = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use **ev.scale** property. Example scale value while zooming out : 0.6803972721099854

```
var i = 300;
$('#element_id').bind('swipemove', function(event){ event.preventDefault();});
$('#element_id').bind('pinchopen pinchclose', function(el, ev) {
    i *= ev.scale;
    $('#element_id').css("width",i+"px");
});
```

Html for this example

```
<div style="width:300px;height:300px;overflow:hidden">
<img width="300" id="element_id" src="http://animal.discovery.com/guides/wild-birds/gallery/mallard_duck.jpg" />
```